# Possible correct combinations of I/O redirection

Tags: bash

```
sqlite -echo test.sqlite < test44.sql > test44.out 1>&2.

sqlite -echo test.sqlite < test44.sql > test44.out 2>&1.
```

Even though swapping the both I/O redirectors, the output hasn't differed.

Comment: Does the `sqlite` command generate any errors or warnings? If not, the result will be the same. Otherwise, with the first line, I'd expect the errors to go to the console. Hmm... no. I'd expect everything to go to the console with the first command, and that the out file is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `1>&2` you redirect standard output to wherever standard error is going.  This is not done often.

With `2>&1` you do the opposite, which is more common.

Doing this:

```
$ echo "hello world" >hello.out 1>&2
hello world

$ cat hello.out
```

I get "hello world" on the error stream, but `>hello.out` also creates an empty `hello.out` file (or truncates it if it exists).

It's the last redirection on the line that "wins", but the file is created when the redirection is parsed left-to-right, before the command is executed.

In you case (those `.` at the end of the command lines that you have is probably a typo, right?):

```
$ sqlite -echo test.sqlite <test44.sql >test44.out 1>&2
```

This ought to work in the equivalent way as my `echo` test above since `sqlite` (or at least `sqlite3` on OpenBSD that I'm testing with), outputs the executed SQL commands to standard output.